# Having issues uploada a new default c# function to AWS Lambda in Visual Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Doing the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-creating-project-in-visual-studio.html).I am getting the following error message when I try to upload my HelloWorld default function to Lambda.

> Error creating Lambda function: User:
> arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/xxxxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to
> perform: iam:PassRole on resource:
> arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbecause no
> identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action

I am having a hard time finding much on this issue. I can see other lambda functions in AWS Explorer.

I have tried looking for PassRole in IAM, nothing. I tried to assign all IAM permissions to the IAM Role. Didn't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On your Lambda Role's Policy add this permission to `iam:PassRole`. Add these lines -

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
        ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
```

Hope this helps!